# add label to a checkbox cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, label

I am a bit new to CakePhp.
I have an input that is a checkbox with a label and i would like to assign a class to the label.

Here is what I have so far:

```
echo $this->Form->input('', array(
               'type' => 'checkbox',
               'label' => 'I agree to the conditions',
               'separator' => '</div><div class="controls">',
               'format' => array('before', 'input', 'label','between', 'after','error'),

               ));
```

the html I would like to have is something like this:

```
<div class="control-group ">
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="checkbox" name="" id="" '> 
                <label class='small_text'> <!-- can't get this one in cake -->
                   I agree to the conditions
            </label>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I got almost all right but i miss the class `small-text` for the `label`. Any idea on how to achieve that? thanx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use following which gives class to label

```
echo $this->Form->input('', array(
'type' => 'checkbox',
'label' => array('class' => 'small_text','text'=>'I agree to the conditions'),
'separator' => '</div><div class="controls">',
'format' => array('before', 'input', 'label','between', 'after','error'),

));
```

Explanation : `'label' => array('class' => 'small_text','text'=>'I agree to the conditions'),` means you are Not Only giving text for label , but also class to label by specifying the parameter `class` . By default as per your code , only Text was passed , so it displayed only text. I added class parameter which specifies class property/attribute for label.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the one given by jQuery.PHP.Magento.com but I'll post my solution as well....
I come up with something like this:

```
$termsAndConditions =  $this->Html->link('Terms And Conditions', 'conditions', array('target' => '_blank'));

$labelConditions = $this->Form->label('agreeToConditions', 'I agree to the  '.$termsAndConditions.' of this site', array(
            'class' => 'small_text',
        ));

        echo $this->Form->input('agreeToConditions', array(
            'type' => 'checkbox',
            'label' => $labelConditions,
            'separator' => '</div><div class="controls">',
            'format' => array('before', 'input', 'label','between', 'after','error'),

            )); 
        ?>
```

I needed to add a link to the label that I didn't mention in the question.

However I think the one provided by jQuery.php.Magento is a bit better as it is more compact and easy to read